# React/Jest/Enzyme - How to test a form submission using an external API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am using a geocoding API to validate an address submission on a form. On form submit, I make a call to the geocoding API, then validate the rest of the form once this is done.

```
class Form extends React.Component {
geocode = (streetAddress, city, postcode) => {
  return Geocode.fromAddress(`${streetAddress} ${city} ${postcode}`);
};

validateAddress = callback => {
  const { streetAddress, city, postcode } = this.state;
  return geocode(streetAddress, city, postcode)
    .then(response => {
      const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
      this.setState({ lat: lat, lng: lng });
      console.log(1);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.setState({ postcodeError: true });
    });
};

validateForm = (error = false) => {
  {
    ...form validation
  }
  if (error === false) {
    this.setState({ showPreview: true });
  }
};

handleSubmit = event => {
  this.validateAddress().then(() => {
    this.validateForm();
  });
};

render() {
  return(...form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}
)
}


}
```

This works fine in Chrome, but when I come to test the interaction in Jest, the geocode promise is not executed at all.

```
    const wrapper = mount(<Form />);
    wrapper.setState(validInputs);
    wrapper
      .find(".submit")
      .first()
      .simulate("submit");
    expect(wrapper.state("showPreview")).toBe(true);
  });
```

From my understanding, this is because Jest `tests complete once they reach the end of their execution` (docs), which means it will not wait for asynchronous code to finish running.

I know I can extract asynchronous methods individually and test them in Jest, but how do I test promises that are called by other methods? For example, I want to make sure that when a user hits submit, my component is running `validateAddress` and `validateForm` in the right order, and handling any errors correctly.

Note: I have mocked the geocoding call as well but have left that out for brevity's sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `jest.mock` or `Proxy`. Also it's worth to split the code (`geocode` and `validateAddress`) into different files and it should be easier, simpler and I think proper :)